# Which classifier is efficient in dealing with test query which belongs to no trained class?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, text-classification

Suppose classifier trained with 5 class, and input query content does not belong to any of the trained class data.

Naive bayes provides and random class as a result here. Which classifier deals best in such scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your setting correctly, you should firstly apply a special classifier in order to distinguish test instances belonging to known classes from ones belonging to unknown classes (novel, outliers). 
This task is called **novelty**, or **anomaly**, or **outlier detection**, see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) or [scikit-learn tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html). 
Then, in order to classify inliners into 5 classes, you can use any ordinary classifier like NB.

There are many methods depending on specific of your data; as a rule of thumb, try One-class SVM or distance-based methods like (covariance.EmpiricalCovariance) or (covariance.MinCovDet) from scikit-learn or, simpler, k-nearest neighbors.